# User profile custom style (per user)

Tags: 7, theming, users

Is there a way to theme a user's profile but make it per user instead of globally on all users?

Comment: are you using the profile2 module or the deprecated user-profile module?

Comment: Its the one that comes with Drupal 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Drupal theme suggestions to specify templates based on any of the users fields.

I've implemented a theme for each of the different roles on my site for instance:

```
function [theme]_preprocess_user_profile(&$vars) {

foreach($vars['elements']['#account']->roles as $role):

    $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'user_profile__'. str_replace(' ','-', $role);

endforeach;

}
```

To do the same with a users name for instance you could do:

```
$vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'user_profile__'. str_replace(' ','-', $vars['elements']['#account']->name);
```

Then make sure you've got the corresponding theme files inside your theme folder. All underscores are converted by Drupal to dashes so a suggestion of user_profile__dave would become user-profile--dave.tpl.php for instance.